# C# Split string emails

Tags: c#, mysql, split

In my table of database **MySQL** I've stored this string example:

```
name.surname@thedomain.com
```

I need spli this string in **C#** for this output

```
NAME SURNAME
```

And tried this solution:

```
string[] emails = strEMail_user.ToString().Split('.');
string newUserName = emails[0].ToUpper().ToString() + " " 
                   + emails[1].ToUpper().ToString();
```

But I've in output this wrong string :

```
NAME SURNAME@THEDOMAIN.
```

Comment: you could find the index of the @ symbol and substring the rest out.

Comment: Did you tried to split the second part on '@' char and taking the first one ?

Comment: While you could split by '@' and then split the first half of that by '.', there is the question of whether all of your names are appropriate to split in that way. i.e. are they necessarily all "given name" dot "family name"?

Comment: Why did you expect the output to be correct based on your code?

Comment: Use a regular expression match instead of all this extra string logic, if this will process for more than a few email addresses.

Comment: email can contain only one `@` char, splitting name and domain name parts, so using Regex here is rather an overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this using a combination of `string.Split` calls, but it would be much neater to use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class to do this.

Your regex should look something like this:

`([a-zA-Z]*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)@thedomain\.com`

You can then use the [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to obtain the values from the matching groups.

Comment: Note: You may need to make some alterations to the regex to account for other characters (for example, double-barrelled surnames) in the names.

Comment: what about domain part if it changes?

Comment: @Andrew: I assumed from the question that the domain is constant and known in advance (e.g., an internal employee database, or similar.) However, I don't think it's much of a stretch to adapt the Regex if that's not the case.

Comment: Neither am I judging nor down voting you, just adjust your answer for OP to use with more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your pattern `name.surname@thedomain.com` then you can just use `Split` with two delimiters, and get first and second parts:

```
var parts = "name.surname@thedomain.com".Split('.', '@');

string name = parts[0];

string surname = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strEMail_user.ToString().Split('@')[0]` as first part of your email, where name and surname are stored. Then you can split that by `.` to get name and surname just like you did, if that's the pattern of your emails.

Comment: The question remains about whether that is appropriate in all cases, for all cultures which will be represented in that database.

Comment: email can contain only one `@` char, splitting name and domain name parts, so using `Regex` here is rather an overhead

Comment: in your connection string(since you use mysql) add following setting: `....; CharSet=utf8;`

Comment: True about the charset and true about the `@`, but that doesn't address the more fundamental question of whether name entries are always suitable for splitting as `<given-name>.<family-name>`. There's a culture-dependent assumption in there which is not always true.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the string `name.surname@thedomain.com` on the `.` character.  That will give you the following pieces:

```
name
surname@thedomain
com
```

Remember, there is a `.com` at the end of your string.  What you want to do is split just the beginning of the email address.  Try splitting the entire email address first on the `@` symbol to return the following pieces:

```
name.surname
thedomain.com
```

Now you can split the first piece on the `.` character to get your name and surname.

Note that this is completely assumes that all of your email addresses are of this form, and ignores cultural differences in first name/last name placement.